# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon ECR Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to deploy a multicontainer Docker application to Elastic Beanstalk. 
My Dockerrun.aws.json file is very simple, and it's the only thing that's uploaded to EB:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "mycontainer",
      "image": "somethingsomething.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myimage",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128
    }
  ]
}
```

In http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html it says that when using a Docker image uploaded to Amazon ECR:

> You do, however, need to provide your instances with permission to
>   access the images in your Amazon ECR repository by adding permissions
>   to your environment's instance profile. You can attach the
>   AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly managed policy to the instance
>   profile to provide read-only access to all Amazon ECR repositories in
>   your account

When deploying the application, it raises the following error:

> ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited.
>   (myimage: CannotPullContainerError: AccessDeniedException: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-xyz
>   is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
>   status code: 400, request id: 4143c35d-)

I added the AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnlyAccess to the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role, but it doesn't change anything...

Help?!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not sure where it's written, but I needed to actually add the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly policy to aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role. AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly contains the GetAuthorizationToken action.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks!! This was not mentioned in any tutorials I read!

Answer (score 18):

per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html#iam-instanceprofile-addperms

1. open https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#roles
2. Choose **aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role**
3. On the Permissions tab, choose Attach policies.
4. select **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly**
5. Choose **Attach policy**